# Kotlin annotation only for annotation parameters

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I'd like to have a Kotlin annotation that can only be used as a parameter on another annotation. Which target should I use for it?

```
// @Target   <- ?
annotation class MyConfigurationEntry(
    val option,
    val value
)

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class MyConfiguration(vararg val entries: MyConfigurationEntry)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is `@Target(AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS)` if you click on that constant you will read:

> Annotation class only

Kotlin version 1.3.41

Comment: And you can see it's the target of `Target`: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.annotation/-target/index.html

Comment: Lol didn't think about that, it's so funny